# just a manipulation problem for statistics

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

I am a little bit confused when i was asked to

Suppose $X_1, X_2,\ldots,X_n$ is a simple random sample from a continuous distribution with density function $f(x)$. Consider the new random variable $T$, defined as:

$$T=\max(X_1, X_2,\ldots,X_n)$$

Find an expression for $g(t)$, the density function of the random variable $T$.

What does this max actually mean? It seems to me it is similar to an MLE problem where I times all the likelihood. Am I right?

because the answer is $P(T\le t)=\prod_i P(X_i\le t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F_X$ be the CDF of the $X_i$ (which are i.i.d), and let $$
  T_n = \max \{X_1,\ldots,X_n\} \text{.}
$$
In plain english, what happens here is that you draw $n$ samples from some population, and then pick that largest one. That's your *sample* $T_n$.

Obviously $P(T_1 \leq x) = P(X_1 \leq x) = F_X(x)$. And since the $X_i$ are all independent, $$
  P(T_2 \leq x) = P(X_1 \leq x, X_2 \leq x) = P(X_1 \leq x)P(X_2 \leq x) = \left(F_X(x)\right)^2 \text{.}
$$
In the general case you get $$
  F_{T_n}(x) = P(T_n \leq x) = P(X_1,\ldots,X_n \leq x) = \prod_{k=1}^n P(X_i \leq x) = \left(F_X(x)\right)^n \text{.}
$$
and from that you find that density by differentiating, i.e. $$
  f_{T_n}(x) = \frac{d}{dx} F_{T_n}(x) = n\left(F_X(x)\right)^{n-1}F_X'(x) =  n\left(F_X(x)\right)^{n-1}f_X(x) \text{.}
$$

If we throw caution to the wind for a second, and treat densities as if they were probabilities, we can easily interpret that result. Let's look at the factors of $f_{T_n}(x)$, i.e. of the "probability" that $T_n = x$, individually.

1. $f_X(x)$. This is simply the "probability" that some $X_i=x$ (for a fixed $i$)
2. $\left(F_X(x)\right)^{n-1}$. This is the probability we get a value less than $x$ exactly (n-1) times.
3. $n$. This accounts for the fact that (1) assumed $i$ is fixed. Since we're taking the maximum of $n$ values, there are $n$ possible choices as to *which* of the values is the maximum.

Comment: yeah i understand all the work after the first step but I have some difficulty to accept the approach to this problem

Comment: @natu It simples uses that $P(A \textrm{and} B) = P(A)P(B)$ if $A,B$ are independent. Since the $X_i$ are independent, the events $X_i \leq x$ are all pairwise independent, and therefore $P(X_1,\ldots,X_n \leq x) = P(X_1 \leq x)\ldots P(X_n \leq x)$. Since the $X_i$ are also all identically distributed, $P(X_1 \leq x) = \ldots = P(X_n \leq x) = F_X(x)$, and the result follows.

Comment: perhaps I should ask why max -> $P(A and B)=P(A)P(B)$ I am just confused what this MAX in here actually mean.

Comment: @natsu That formula's got nothing to do with the fact that we're dealing with a maximum. That's true for *any* pair of independent events $A,B$!

Comment: @natsu I tried to explain a bit more verbosely

Comment: so i didnt really have to care about the Max here right

Comment: @natsu Dunno what you mean by that. You're computing the CDF and PDF for $T_n = \max \{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$, so you the $\max$ will play a role somewhere. But that particular formula $P(A \textrm{ and } B) = P(A)P(B)$, that holds for all independent events...